# How to insert text in Toast UI Editor [React] for button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toast-ui-editor

How to insert the text in editor for the button click on toast ui react editor
We have created a separate button in toastui editor tab, In below code we have inserted the text in console for the button click, we want to insert the same in Editor

```
import React from "react";
import "@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor.css";
import { Editor } from "@toast-ui/react-editor";

function Editor4() {
  let editorRef = React.createRef();

  //Adding item based on button click
  const handleClick = () => {
    editorRef.current
      .getInstance()
      .addCommand("markdown", "additem", function additem() {
        console.log("ButtonClicked");
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Editor
          initialValue="Hello"
          previewStyle="vertical"
          height="400px"
          initialEditType="markdown"
          ref={editorRef}
          toolbarItems={[
            [
              "heading",
              "bold",
              {
                name: "Button",
                tooltip: "myItem",
                command: "additem",
                className: "toastui-editor-toolbar-icons",
                text: "V",
              }]
          ]}
        />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>makeBold</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the porpertie `insertText(YourText: string)`

Example:

```
 editorRef.current.getInstance().insertText('ButtonClicked')
```